# log4j:ERROR No output stream or file set for the appender named [file]

Tags: java, logging, log4j

This is my log4j.properties file.

```
log =/src/main/resources 
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout
# Define the file appender  
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/logger.log 
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=12MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
# configuration to print on console
 log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
 log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
 log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
 #--------------------------------------------------------------------#
```

And this is my test class .logs are printing in console but not writing in log files can anyone tell what's wrong here i am getting error like
log4j:ERROR No output stream or file set for the appender named [file].

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

public class Test {

    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Test.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("hello");

        PropertyConfigurator.configure("/src/main/resources/log4j.properties");
 
        logger.debug("Log4j appender configuration is successful !!");
        logger.info("Log4j appender configuration is successful info!!");

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this string is correct? log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/logger.log. I seem your SpEl don't resolve. You need to check your output and make sure of this